# Does C++ std::hex reverse bytes order? (printing decimal as hexadecimal)

Tags: c++, hex, byte, endianness

I'm having some trouble understanding the following C++ code:

```
std::cout << std::hex << 61183 << std::endl; // prints eeff
```

I'm working on a little-endian machine (Intel x86-64), and I wanted to understand, at bit and byte level, how that result is produced, so I wrote the following table for a least significant bit architecture.

[image]

As you can see, I expected the output of the line of code to be `FFEE` instead of `EEFF`. So I must have missed something while making that table, but I don't really see what. Is `std::hex` affected by the endianness of a computer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Endianness is about how to store numbers in byte-addressed memory.

On the other hand, `std::hex` produces hexadecimal text.

`0x1000 * 14 + 0x100 * 14 + 0x10 * 15 + 0x1 * 15 == 61183`, so `61183` is `EEFF` in hexadecimal.

This won't be affected by endianness.

Comment: I think I messed up LSB with the column order in my table.

Answer (score 1):

`61183` in hexadecimal is `EEFF`.

Endianness is all to do with how some number values are stored in memory, not how conversions from one radix to another should be defined. Hence the output of `std::hex` is not contingent on endianness, although it might be a factor in the internal calculations.